# Is $x(t/2)$ a causal/memoryless system?

Tags: signal-processing, nonlinear-system

Basically, is any system $$y(t) =x(\alpha t)$$ a causal system? Where $0<\alpha<1$ (a fraction) and $t>0$.

I know that a causal system depends only on current or previous inputs, however, does multiplying the variable $t$ by a fraction make the system causal or non-causal?

Comment: Well if $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$ and $t \gt 0$ then $\alpha t \lt t$, so $y(t)$ depends only on a previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the definition following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system):

> ***Defintion.*** Let system $y:F([0;\infty),S)\to F([0;\infty),S)$, where $S$ is some space and $F([0,\infty),S)$ if the space of functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $S$. The system $y$ is said to be is *causal* iff for every two input signals $x_1,x_2\in F([0,\infty);S)$ such that there exist $t_0\in [0,\infty)$ so that 
>   $$
> x_1(t)=x_2(t),\ \text{for every }t\le t_0,\ \ \text{it holds that }\ y(x_1(t))=y(x_2(t)),\text{ for every }t\le t_0,
> $$

Then your system is causal, which can be proved by 
\begin{align*}
y(x_1(t)):=x_1(\alpha t) = x_2(\alpha t) =:y(x_2(t)), \text{ for every }t\le t_0,
\end{align*}
as $\alpha t\le t$ for every $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

I would recommend checking causality of other systems like 
$$y(x(t)):=x(\alpha^{-1}t),\quad y(x(t)):=\int_0^{\alpha t}x(s)ds+ x(1),\quad y(x(t)):=\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|x(s)|\quad y(x(t)):= x(\sin(2^{-1}\pi t)),\quad y(x(t)):= \sin(2^{-1}\pi x( t)).
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you forget for a minute the $t<0$ constraint:
It is not casual since for any t<0 it will depend on the future.
It is not memoryless since at any given t is depends on the past.

Now if $t>0$ then $t/2<t$ so it is casual but again not memoryless